# Повернуть SVG-элемент, как изображение

Tags: javascript, css, html5, svg, css-animation

Я пытался сделать так, чтобы круг находился на одном месте и вращался вокруг себя, но он вращается по странице. Я только начинаю изучать SVG и застрял на этом моменте.

```js
document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', () => {
  document.querySelector('.kolo svg #pomidor').classList.add('pomidor');
})
```

```css
#pomidor {
  transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  opacity: 1;
  transition: all 4s;
}

#pomidor.pomidor {
  opacity: 1;
  transform: rotate(-360deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="kolo">
  <svg width="246px" height="133px" viewBox="0 0 246 133" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
          <g id="pomidor">
            <g id="left">
              <path d="M188.669237,2.85577743 L220.007541,78.7916793 C215.011273,80.9577555 209.503344,82.159 203.7202,82.159 C181.0712,82.159 162.6422,63.731 162.6422,41.08 C162.6422,23.7394433 173.442929,8.87328458 188.669237,2.85577743 Z" id="tomato-dark" fill="#ED2D24">
              </path>         
            </g>
            <g id="right">
              <path d="M203.7202,0.0003 C198.1552,0.0003 192.8472,1.1183 188.0022,3.1323 L219.4392,79.0273 C234.3122,72.8423 244.8002,58.1653 244.8002,41.0803 C244.8002,18.4283 226.3712,0.0003 203.7202,0.0003" id="tomato-light" fill="green">
              </path>           
            </g>
          </g>
    </svg>
</div>
<button> Rotate circle</button>
```

Comment: ассоциация:https://stackoverflow.com/q/58308244/7394871

Comment: Я выбрал этот топик для перевода, так как очень часто встречаются вопросы по трансформации SVG, - вращение, масштабирование, перемещение. Никакой магии действительно нет. В SVG абсолютное позиционирование и начало координат находится в левом правом углу и поэтому все расчеты ведутся от него. Чтобы мучительно долго не искать центр вращения фигуры берется замечательное свойство CSS  `transform-box: fill-box`;

Answer (score 2):

Установите для CSS-свойства `transform-box` значение `fill-box`, чтобы фигура вращалась вокруг своего собственного центра, а не вокруг левого верхнего угла `viewBox`.

```js
document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', () => {
  document.querySelector('.kolo svg #pomidor').classList.add('pomidor');
})
```

```css
#pomidor {
  transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  transform-box: fill-box;
  opacity: 1;
  transition: all 4s;
}

#pomidor.pomidor {
  opacity: 1;
  transform: rotate(-360deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="kolo">
  <svg width="246px" height="133px" viewBox="0 0 246 133" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
          <g id="pomidor">
            <g id="left">
              <path d="M188.669237,2.85577743 L220.007541,78.7916793 C215.011273,80.9577555 209.503344,82.159 203.7202,82.159 C181.0712,82.159 162.6422,63.731 162.6422,41.08 C162.6422,23.7394433 173.442929,8.87328458 188.669237,2.85577743 Z" id="tomato-dark" fill="#ED2D24">
              </path>         
            </g>
            <g id="right">
              <path d="M203.7202,0.0003 C198.1552,0.0003 192.8472,1.1183 188.0022,3.1323 L219.4392,79.0273 C234.3122,72.8423 244.8002,58.1653 244.8002,41.0803 C244.8002,18.4283 226.3712,0.0003 203.7202,0.0003" id="tomato-light" fill="green">
              </path>           
            </g>
          </g>
    </svg>
</div>
<button> Rotate circle</button>
```

Источник ответа: [@RobertLongson](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58313556/7394871)

Answer (score 2):

Вам нужно настроить `transform-origin`, чтобы установить точку трансформации в середине этого круга (я использовал плагин линейки в своем браузере, чтобы легко найти его, никакой магии):

```js
document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', () => {
  document.querySelector('.kolo svg #pomidor').classList.add('pomidor');
})
```

```css
#pomidor {
  transform-origin:  204px 41px;
  opacity: 1;
  transition: all 4s;
}

#pomidor.pomidor {
  opacity: 1;
  transform: rotate(-360deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="kolo">
  <svg width="246px" height="133px" viewBox="0 0 246 133" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
          <g id="pomidor">
            <g id="left">
              <path d="M188.669237,2.85577743 L220.007541,78.7916793 C215.011273,80.9577555 209.503344,82.159 203.7202,82.159 C181.0712,82.159 162.6422,63.731 162.6422,41.08 C162.6422,23.7394433 173.442929,8.87328458 188.669237,2.85577743 Z" id="tomato-dark" fill="#ED2D24">
              </path>         
            </g>
            <g id="right">
              <path d="M203.7202,0.0003 C198.1552,0.0003 192.8472,1.1183 188.0022,3.1323 L219.4392,79.0273 C234.3122,72.8423 244.8002,58.1653 244.8002,41.0803 C244.8002,18.4283 226.3712,0.0003 203.7202,0.0003" id="tomato-light" fill="green">
              </path>           
            </g>
          </g>
    </svg>
</div>
<button> Rotate circle</button>
```

**Пример вращения колеса с одновременным перемещением**

```js
document.querySelector("button").addEventListener("click", () => {
  document.querySelector(".kolo svg #pomidor").classList.add("pomidor");
  document.querySelector(".kolo #test").classList.add("pomidor");
});
```

```css
#pomidor {
  transform-origin: 204px 41px;
  opacity: 1;
  transition: all 4s;
}
#test {
  transition: 4s;
}
#test.pomidor {
  transform: translatex(-65%);
}
#pomidor.pomidor {
  opacity: 1;
  transform: rotate(-360deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="kolo">
  <svg id="test" width="246px" height="133px" viewBox="0 0 246 133" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
          <g id="pomidor">               
            <g id="left">
              <path d="M188.669237,2.85577743 L220.007541,78.7916793 C215.011273,80.9577555 209.503344,82.159 203.7202,82.159 C181.0712,82.159 162.6422,63.731 162.6422,41.08 C162.6422,23.7394433 173.442929,8.87328458 188.669237,2.85577743 Z" id="tomato-dark" fill="#ED2D24">
              </path> 
            </g>
            <g id="right">
              <path d="M203.7202,0.0003 C198.1552,0.0003 192.8472,1.1183 188.0022,3.1323 L219.4392,79.0273 C234.3122,72.8423 244.8002,58.1653 244.8002,41.0803 C244.8002,18.4283 226.3712,0.0003 203.7202,0.0003" id="tomato-light" fill="green">
              </path>           
            </g>
          </g>
    </svg>
</div>
<button> Rotate circle</button>
```

Источник ответа: [@G-Cyr](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58308462/7394871)